# How to sync cookie between two different domain in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cookies

How to sync cookie between two different domain in **Nodejs**?

Example:

**Domain 1**: `https://my-frontend.com`

**Domain 2**: `https://my-backend.com`

My expected is when user login from **Domain 1**, It will be send request (user information) to **Domain 2** and **Domain 2** will setCookie then sync cookie with **Domain 1**

Who can help me or any idea?

Comment: wait - what is the problem you are trying to solve? Can you use http://my-fe.mydomain.com and http://my-be.mypomain.com?

Comment: @DraganS  my case has to handle cookies with different domain. I deloyed backend to heroku and frontend to netlify, it's between different domain so i cannot sync cookie

Comment: @DraganS  do you have any solution or idea for different domain cookie sync?

Comment: not really. I would go with JS/NODE.JS on domain1 and call domain2 via node.js - used like a light proxy.  This is often used pattern - FE - BFF - Java/Go/PhP (BFF- backend for frontend)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. The solution is very easy for my project.

**Adding this fixed it.**

> app.set("trust proxy", 1);

I hope it does its job.