# Node app has an HTML page call another JavaScript file? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Simple setup question here. I have my node project which has opened a localhost server running an html page. From that html page, how can I call another script?

`index.js`

```
var http = require('http');
var fileSystem = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp){
    fileSystem.readFile('./main.html', function(error, fileContent){
        if(error){
            resp.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            resp.end('Error');
        }
        else{
            resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            resp.write(fileContent);
            resp.end();
        }
    });
});

server.listen(8080);

console.log('Listening at: localhost:8080');
```

`main.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <p>Hello world! Node is awesome, is it not?</p> 
        <script src="new_script.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

This page shows the `<p>` text and runs on localhost:8080, then gives the error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

This is the `new_script.js` which is not running:

```
alert("new_script.js called");
test1 = 123; test2 = 543; 
test3 = test1*test2;
alert(test3);
```

And my file folder structure is flat, everything is there:

[image]

So how can I get started calling more JavaScript into my loaded up html page on my node.js server?

Comment: open network in browser, the right click on record new_script and click open in new tab. Almost sure that you will see 404 page

Comment: ah - wait - you have a "hand-made" server. You are not serving js file there. https://expressjs.com/ - this may help

Comment: @DraganS  Please help me this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694418/how-to-sync-cookie-between-two-different-domain-in-nodejs

Comment: I have moved the answer to its own CW post. Please always add answers as an answer post, rather than merged into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

This got resolved by using Express.js, which is really convenient.

```
npm install express --save
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static("./js"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //res.send('Hello World!')
  res.sendFile('./main.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Now all the code is the same, except I'm telling the project to use the folder "js/" to find JavaScript files. So I just moved `new_script.js` in there and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current web site at localhost:8080 will do nothing but serve out a Html page with the contents of main.html, for *all* request paths. So the call to localhost:8080/new_script.js, the file referenced in your main page, will also be returned the contents of your main.html and not the contents of that new_script.js file. The first occurrence of the `<` character in your main.html probably explains that error message.

Unless you are doing this for purely academic purposes, you should be using something like [Express](https://expressjs.com) if you want to code a real web site.

If you really want to do this with plain Node, then you have to parse and handle every url on the `request` object. You have to do something rather laborious such as:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp){
    if (req.url === "/") {
        fileSystem.readFile('./main.html', function(error, fileContent){
            if(error){
               resp.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
               resp.end('Error');
            }
           else{
               resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
               resp.write(fileContent);
               resp.end();
            }
        });
    } else if (req.url === "/new_script.js") {
        fileSystem.readFile('./new_script.js', function(error, fileContent){
            if(error){
               resp.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
               resp.end('Error');
            }
           else{
               resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
               resp.write(fileContent);
               resp.end();
            }
        });
    } else {
       resp.writeHead(404);
       resp.end("Not found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah this is just a learning exercise for now. I guess it's much better to have express then.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing me in the right direction with express. I'll update the OP with what worked in case others need help.